# How can i return a Django ModelForm through an Jquery Ajax call?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Initially i am loading a modelform with an instance in the template end. But i have to change the instance upon some action using ajax and then refresh the form in the template end. Please suggest me is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the server view uses a *`ModelForm`* to *render* a HTML snippet representing an *instance* of a *`Model`* (i.e. `{{ myform.as_p }}` or similar) that is then placed in a larger template representing an entire HTML document and finally sent to the client.

You need to create a second view that will render and return only the HTML snippet representing the form. From your original template you can then create an ajax call to your new view, which will return the forms HTML. You can replace your existing form with this via jQuery.

view:

```
def my_second_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'my_second_form.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

template:

```
    <form action="/url/to/my_second_form/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: The form is refreshing with the instance data but the instance is not changing. The instance which i used initially to load the ModelForm, it is still the same. Can you please provide me some more information in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

#djanog function.

```
def get_doctor_Data(request):
            get_doctor = Doctor.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('dept_id'))
            
            # Set initial value of django forms input and send as ajax respons
            # If you getting any type of error so use form_name.as_p() method.
            edit_form = AddDoctorForm(initial={'name':get_doctor.name, 'dep_id':get_doctor.id})
    
            return HttpResponse(edit_form)
```

// Ajax method call.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/department/get_department_Data/',
        type: 'GET',
        data : {'dept_id': $(this).attr('id')},
        success:(data)=>{
          if(data){
            // open modal
            $('#basicModal').modal('show'); 

            // Django forms get using ajax
            $('#editForm').html(data)
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).